# FullCalendar Not Displaying Data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, date, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using fullCalendar in my MVC project. I downloaded fullCalendar from Nuget but it doesn't display my data on the calendar. I can get my data but it is not displaying.

What is going wrong in my code?

**MVC action method:**

```
  public JsonResult GetEvents()
  {
    dbContext = new Context();
    var events = dbContext.Schedule.ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
  }
```

**View:**

I think the GenerateCalendar function is not working.

```
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/PanelJS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/PanelJS/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"@Url.Action("GetEvents","Schedule")",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data,function(i,v)
                    {
                        events.push({
                            title: v.Name,
                            start: v.Date,
                            end: v.EndDate,
                            location:v.Location

                        });
                        console.log(events);
                    })
                    GenerateCalendar(events);
                },
                error:function(error)
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });

            function GenerateCalendar(events)
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                    {
                        contentHeight: 400,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        color:'lightBlue',
                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right:'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        events:events
                    })
            }
        });
</script>
```

Console result ;

```
end: "10/05/2018 "location: "Chicago" start: "09/05/2018" title: "MyEvent"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the console output it looks like your dates are being supplied as strings in an ambiguous format. fullCalendar / momentJS will not understand that without being explicitly told what you format is being used. It could be `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`. There is no way for the parser to know what to do with it.

Therefore fullCalendar will not be able to use this data as an event, because it doesn't understand the start and end dates.

The date and time formats accepted by fullCalendar are the same as those accepted by momentJS (since it uses momentJS to work with dates). This is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment and in more detail here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Therefor, you can either

1) *(recommended)* Re-write your server-side code so that it returns dates in ISO format. Generally if you are using DateTime objects in your C# code, then the .NET JSON serialiser will do that for you automatically. Since you're directly serialising the result of an Entity Framework query into JSON, then I would suspect that the `Date` and `EndDate` properties of your `Schedule` class are strings rather than DateTimes, which in turn means that you may be storing dates as strings within your database. If so, that is a bad practice which you should fix immediately by storing dates as `datetime` columns. Dates are not strings, they are dates. What you see on screen (e.g. 09/05/2018) is merely one of many possible *representations* of that date in a human-readable form. It is not a good format for actually *storing* the date information.

OR

2) *(alternative)* If that's not the case, or not possible for some reason, then tell momentJS to parse the dates according to the format you're supplying and then pass the data to fullCalendar as a moment object, e.g.

```
events.push({
  title: v.Name,
  start: moment(v.Date, "DD/MM/YYYY"),
  end: moment(v.EndDate, "DD/MM/YYYY"),
  location: v.Location
});
```

In-depth documentation of the format-specific parsing functionality in momentJS can be found here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved my problem before your answer. I changed my columns type string to datetime.

Comment: @user9582479 glad you solved it, although you should maybe have considered deleting the question in that case. But no problem... in case it's useful to people reading in future with a similar problem, if the answer is correct then please consider marking as "accepted" and/or upvoting so that others can see it's relevant. Thanks.